# I can't make Django-ratings work

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-ratings

I'm using this app of django : 'Django-ratings', and I'm working with it for few days now, but I can't make it work, I don't know what's the problem in my code.

I added `'djangoratings'`, to my INSTALLED_APPS, then I added the field `rating = RatingField(range=5)` to the model I want to be rated.

This is my view

```
def votos(request, self):
if request.is_ajax():
    form = UbicacionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        u = form.save(commit=False)
        u.user = request.user
        u.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        Ubicacion.rating.add(score=self.rating, user=self.user, ip_address=self.ip_address)

        data = '<ul>'
        for ubicacion.rating in ubicaciones:
            data += '<li>%s %s s</li>' % (ubicacion.rating.score, ubicacion.rating.votes)
        data += '</ul>'

        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ok': True, 'msg': data}), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ok':False, 'msg':'No fue valido!'}), mimetype='application/json')
```

My template:

{% load ratings %}

```
                {% csrf_token %}
                <td><input name="star" type="radio" class="star" value= "1"/></td> 
                <td><input name="star" type="radio" class="star" value= "2"/></td> 
                <td><input name="star" type="radio" class="star" value= "3"/></td> 
                <td><input name="star" type="radio" class="star" value= "4"/></td> 
                <td><input name="star" type="radio" class="star" value= "5"/></td> 

                {% rating_by_request request on ubicaciones.rating as vote %}
                {% if vote %}
                <td> {{ vote }}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td> Sorry, no one has voted yet!</td>
                {% endif %}`
```

My ajax function:

```
    $(".star").click(function(){
        var val = $(this).data("value");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "votos",
            data : {
                "val" : val
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

My modelform:

```
class UbicacionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Ubicacion
```

My url

```
          url(r'rate/(?P<object_id>\d*)/(?P<score>\d*)/', AddRatingFromModel(), {
                       'app_label': 'gmaps',
                       'model': 'ubicacion',
                       'field_name': 'rating',
                      }),
```

The new columns that this app should create, it creates inside of the model that I want to rated, "rating_vote" and "rating_score" are both in the database, but with 0 values :/

Answer (score 1):

Currently in your `votos` view you are populating a `UbicacionForm` with the POST data.  You are sending a single value, `val`, which is the rating you want to add.

This model form is looking to create or load a Ubicacion but this will never be valid as you only have a single value (that I assume isn't actually part of an `Ubicacion`).

.

Additionally you have a second url `rate/(?P<object_id>\d*)/(?P<score>\d*)/` that is not being utilised.

Change your ajax request to point to the django-ratings url and not to `votos`

```
$(".star").click(function(){
    var val = $(this).data("value"),

        // Get the pk of the ubicacion from somewhere in your page
        ubicacion_pk = 1,

        // Build the url
        url = '/rate/' + ubicacion_pk + '/' + val + '/';


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```